# Convert between Java and C++ class instance when passing as arguments of wrapped class

Tags: java, c++, swig

Given an arbitrary Java class, say

```
public class Coord {
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double z;

    public Coord(double x, double y, double z) {
         this.x = x; this.y = y; this.z = z;
    }
}
```

and an arbitrary C++ class (or struct), say the C++11 STL class `std::array<double, 3>`,

and a C++ class that is wrapped using Swig to generate a Java proxy class, e.g.

```
class Object {
    move_center(std::array<double, 3> vec) {
        // C++ code
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to write in Java

```
Object obj;
// initialize obj
Coord vec = new Coord(1.5,2.5,3.5);
obj.move_center(vec);
```

and to have the wrapper construct a `std::array<double, 3>` with the values `vec[0] = 1.5` etc.

I am aware that I could define a `Coord` class in C++, let Swig wrap it and use the proxy `Coord` in Java, but there are two reasons why not to do it:

- The C++ Library interface would have to change
- Parts of the Java code that use the Java `Coord` class would be slowed down by having to use the proxy now (or the Java code has to deal with two coord classes, one native one proxy, and convert between the two all the time)

I can imagine the way to go would be to use an `i`-file and use `typemap`

```
%typemap(jstype) std::array<double, 3> "com.foo.bar.Coord"
```

but from there I do not really know where to go.

Comment: You're on the right track with your typemap there, but you'll need a few more typemaps to complete it. It's very solveable though, I'll write up a solution over the weekend. (Note: the solution would be slightly simpler if your Java `Coord` type used an array with 3 elements internally instead of exposing x,y,z individually but that's not a deal breaker)

Comment: @Flexo Cool, I'm looking forward to it! (I will need 2 or 3 such typemaps, if I have the solution to the more complex case, I will be able to modify it for the other cases, too, so it will be very helpfull)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of considerations to this and several possible ways to solve this, so I'll work through a few of them in what I see as a logical order.

I started out by creating a test header file to work with in my demos, which took minor tweaks from what you showed:

```cpp
#include <array>

struct Object {
    void move_center(std::array<double, 3> vec) {
        // C++ code
    }
};
```

First up if you're using a sufficiently recent version of SWIG (definitely newer than 3.0.2, not sure exactly which version though) you'll have some library support for `std::array` we can use as a starting point.

```cpp
%module test

%{
#include "test.hh"
%}

%include <std_array.i>
%template(Vec3) std::array<double, 3>;

%include "test.hh"
```

That's sufficient as a starting point, you get a usable interface that takes a type, `Vec3` that's a useable wrapped form of `std::array<double, 3>`.

Clearly this doesn't actually meet your requirement though of using `Coord`, so we want to write a few typemaps to convert between the Java/C++ types at function call time. You can actually do that in several places. The simplest is to write it as a javain typemap:

```cpp
%module test

%{
#include "test.hh"
%}

%include <std_array.i>
%template(Vec3) std::array<double, 3>;

%typemap(jstype) std::array<double, 3> "Coord"
%typemap(javain,pre="    Vec3 temp$javainput = new Vec3();\n"
                    "    temp$javainput.set(0, $javainput.x);\n"
                    "    temp$javainput.set(1, $javainput.y);\n"
                    "    temp$javainput.set(2, $javainput.z);",
         pgcppname="temp$javainput") std::array<double, 3>, const std::array<double, 3>& "$javaclassname.getCPtr(temp$javainput)"

%include "test.hh"
```

Basically all this does above the typemap you showed us is insert code into generated Java function calls. This code just reads out x,y,z and puts them into a temporary `Vec3` created specifically for the duration of the call.

(If you wanted to you can add a javaout typemap for returning these from C++ functions and another variant with a post attribute that supports non-const references, details on request)

You'll notice here that although it meets the functional requirements you asked for, another goal was to avoid excessive cross-language function calls, but here we've got 4 extra including one memory allocation.

So to address this we can start to make our interface a bit smarter. SWIG has (for ages) had some helper code for arrays in its library, arrays_java.i. We can use that to construct our temporary C++ object in a single call, by using `%extend` to add a new constructor that takes a `double[3]` as an input:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.hh"
#include <algorithm>
%}

%include <std_array.i>
%include <arrays_java.i>

%template(Vec3) std::array<double, 3>;

%extend std::array<double, 3> {
  std::array<double, 3>(double in[3]) {
    std::array<double, 3> temp;
    std::copy_n(in, 3, std::begin(temp));
    return new std::array<double, 3>(temp);
  }
}

%typemap(jstype) std::array<double, 3> "Coord"
%typemap(javain,pre="    Vec3 temp$javainput = new Vec3(new double[]{$javainput.x, $javainput.y, $javainput.z});",
         pgcppname="temp$javainput") std::array<double, 3>, const std::array<double, 3>& "$javaclassname.getCPtr(temp$javainput)"

%include "test.hh"
```

We can do better than this though, why not move the construction of the temporary out of Java and into C++ instead. As a next step I wanted to have SWIG pass a `double[3]` to C++ and then massage that inside an in typemap. I tried the following:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.hh"
#include <algorithm>
%}

%include <arrays_java.i>

%apply double[3] { std::array<double, 3> };
%typemap(jstype) std::array<double, 3> "Coord"
%typemap(javain) std::array<double, 3>, const std::array<double, 3>& "new double[]{$javainput.x, $javainput.y, $javainput.z}"

%typemap(in) std::array<double, 3> //....

%include "test.hh"
```

Notice though that we've now dropped the requirement for std_array.i in the SWIG library and are just relying on arrays_java.i. Although this didn't actually work (the `%apply` isn't valid here).

That isn't a big problem really and I didn't spend much time on it, because we can work around it by writing the JNI calls provided by arrays_java ourselves anyway:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.hh"
#include <algorithm>
%}


%typemap(jstype) std::array<double, 3> "Coord"
%typemap(javain) std::array<double, 3>, const std::array<double, 3>& "new double[]{$javainput.x, $javainput.y, $javainput.z}"
%typemap(jtype) std::array<double, 3> "double[]"
%typemap(jni) std::array<double, 3> "jdoubleArray"
%typemap(in) std::array<double, 3> {
  if (!$input || JCALL1(GetArrayLength, jenv, $input) != 3) {
    SWIG_JavaThrowException(jenv, SWIG_JavaIndexOutOfBoundsException, "incorrect array size");
    return $null;
  }
  double *arr = JCALL2(GetDoubleArrayElements, jenv, $input, NULL);
  std::copy_n(arr, 3, $1.begin());
  JCALL3(ReleaseDoubleArrayElements, jenv, $input, arr, JNI_ABORT);
}

%include "test.hh"
```

This is starting to get as close as possible to the minimal overhead wrapping we're aiming for. We write just enough JNI to allow us to copy the whole `double[]` array into the `std::array` in one go. (Your C++ compiler ought to do a good job of optimising that copy operation). We're still allocating a temporary array of 3 doubles inside Java, that's largely unavoidable in this approach because we don't have a way to increase the number of arguments passed to C++, it's only  possible to decrease that number.

If you wanted to an argout typemap could support pass by non-const reference to functions that modified the inputs. You'd want to use the last argument of the `GetDoubleArrayElements` call to see if it was a copy or not and save the unmapping until the argout typemap and make your own copy back at that point.

As a totally alternative approach we could have chosen to pass the `Coord` object all the way to the in typemap as a jobject and made 3 JNI calls there to get the x, y and z member variable values at that point. Personally I didn't like that idea as much as the above with arrays and I'd use the above example to make an argument for storing the components of your `Coord` class as an array internally and exposing them using accessor functions inside Java if you wanted to give them names.

Comment: Impressive. I tested it and it works. I'm trying now to understand everything you wrote and to implement the conversion in the C++ to Java direction. If I do not manage I will post another comment.

Comment: The conversion from C++ to Java now works as well: `%typemap(javaout) std::array<double, 3> { return new Coord($jnicall[0], $jnicall[1],  $jnicall[2]); }` and `%typemap(out) std::array<double, 3> { $result = JCALL1(NewDoubleArray, jenv, 3); JCALL4(SetDoubleArrayRegion, jenv, $result, 0, 3, $1.begin()); }`

Comment: @matec not 100% sure (can't test right now) but I think you'll be calling your function 3 times in the javaout typemap. You almost certainly want to save the return from $jnicall into a local variable and use that to read each component of the `Vec3` for construction of the `Coord` instead.